# Unexpected behaviour when comparing tuple with python

Tags: python-3.x, singleton, comparison, nan

I have some tuple with equal dimensions and some of them contain `None` or `NaN` elements.
I though that those with `NaN` inside would not compare equals, but in fact some do compare equals.

I have read [Value Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) from the Python Documentation, especially the part saying:

> Sequences compare lexicographically using comparison of corresponding
>   elements, whereby reflexivity of the elements is enforced.
>
> In enforcing reflexivity of elements, the comparison of collections
>   assumes that for a collection element x, x == x is always true. Based
>   on that assumption, element identity is compared first, and element
>   comparison is performed only for distinct elements. This approach
>   yields the same result as a strict element comparison would, if the
>   compared elements are reflexive. For non-reflexive elements, the
>   result is different than for strict element comparison, and may be
>   surprising: The non-reflexive not-a-number values for example result
>   in the following comparison behavior when used in a list:
>
> ```
> >>> nan = float('NaN')
> >>> nan is nan     # True
> >>> nan == nan     # False     <-- the defined non-reflexive behavior of NaN
> >>> [nan] == [nan] # True  <-- list enforces reflexivity and tests identity first
> ```

Here the MCVE which led me to ask the question:

```
import numpy as np

# [1]
x = (12, float('nan'), 'test')
x == (12, float('nan'), 'test') # False

# [2]
y = (12, np.nan, 'test')
y == (12, np.nan, 'test') # True

# [3]
u = float('nan')
q = (12, u, 'test')
q == (12, u, 'test') # True

# [4]
v = (12, None, 'test')
v == (12, None, 'test') # True
```

So, if I have properly understood - lets talk about container of same length - **container comparison** works as follow:

- It compares element-wise;
- First it checks if `x_i is y_i`;
- If not it checks if `x_i == y_i`;
- If *identity* **or** *equality* fails for at least one element, it returns `False`, otherwise `True`.

And this is somehow surprising!

I also have discovered than `numpy.nan` is a Singleton:

```
np.nan is np.nan  # True
```

And it not something like:

```
class test:
    @property
    def nan(self):
        return float('nan')
inst = test()
inst.nan is inst.nan # False
```

My questions are:

- Am I correct in my reasoning or have I missed something else?
- Is there another way to compare in Python that will ensure equality only?

Comment: I'm not an expert in Python semantics, but based on the examples, your reasoning appears to be correct.